# How can I exclude both the .git directories and the node_modules directory when using zip?

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I want to zip all contents of the present directory into a zip file.
While doing this I want to exclude both the .git directory and the node_modules directory.

These commands will exclude .git dir's, but fail to exclude node_modules:

```
zip -r output.zip . -x '*.git*' -x 'node_modules'

zip -r output.zip . -x '*.git*' 'node_modules'
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about Linux utilities or commands. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Second example looks correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please adjust your command to:

```
zip -r output.zip . -x '*.git*' -x '*node_modules*'
```